# Copy matching value from one df to another given multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have two dataframes. The first, df1, has a non-unique ID and a timestamp value in ms. The other, df2, has the non-unique ID, a separate unique ID, a start time and an end time (both in ms).

I need to get the correct unique ID for each row in df1 from df2. I would do this by...

1. match each non-unique ID in df1 to the relevant series of rows in df2
2. of those rows, find the one with the start and end range that contains the timestamp in df1
3. get the unique ID from the resulting row and copy it to a new column in df1

I don't think I can use pd.merge since I need to compare the df1 timestamp to two different columns in df2. I would think df.apply is my answer, but I can't figure it out.

Here is some dummy code:

```
df1_dict = {
    'nonunique_id': ['abc','def','ghi','jkl'],
    'timestamp': [164.3,2071.2,1001.7,846.4]
}

df2_dict = {
    'nonunique_id': ['abc','abc','def','def','ghi','ghi','jkl','jkl'],
    'unique_id': ['a162c1','md85k','dk102','l394j','dj4n5','s092k','dh567','57ghed0'],
    'time_start': [160,167,2065,2089,1000,1010,840,876],
    'time_end': [166,170,2088,3000,1009,1023,875,880]
}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1_dict)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2_dict)
```

And here is a manual test...

```
df2['unique_id'][(df2['nonunique_id'].eq('abc')) & (df2['time_start']<=164.3) & (df2['time_end']>=164.3)]
```

...which returns the expected output (the relevant unique ID from df2):

> 0    a162c1
>
> Name: unique_id, dtype: object

**I'd like a function that can apply the above manual test automatically, and copy the results to a new column in df1.**

I tried this...

```
def unique_id_fetcher(nonunique_id,timestamp):
    cond_1 = df2['nonunique_id'].eq(nonunique_id)
    cond_2 = df2['time_start']<=timestamp
    cond_3 = df2['time_end']>=timestamp
    
    unique_id = df2['unique_id'][(cond_1) & (cond_2) & (cond_3)]
    
    return unique_id

df1['unique_id'] = df1.apply(unique_id_fetcher(df1['nonunique_id'],df1['timestamp']))
```

...but that results in:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

(*Edited for clarity*)

Comment: whats your expected output?

Comment: Using the dummy code, I'd expect:
`0 a162c1`
`Name: unique_id, dtype: object`

(see first block of highlighted text above).

In general, expected output is the unique_id from df2.

Comment: understood, added answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

you can do a caretsian product of both dataframes and do a merge, then apply your logic

you create a dict and map the values back onto your df1 using non_unique_id as the key.

```
df1['key'] = 'var'
df2['key'] = 'var'
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2,on=['key','nonunique_id'],how='outer')

df4 = df3.loc[
    (df3["timestamp"] >= df3["time_start"]) & (df3["timestamp"] <= df3["time_end"])
]

d = dict(zip(df4['nonunique_id'],df4['unique_id']))

df1['unique_id'] = df1['nonunique_id'].map(d)

print(df1.drop('key',axis=1))

  nonunique_id  timestamp unique_id
0          abc      164.3    a162c1
1          def     2071.2     dk102
2          ghi     1001.7     dj4n5
3          jkl      846.4     dh567
```

Comment: Yes! This is the expected output, thanks. Let me sit with this method for a bit.

Comment: no problemo, let me know if you need any additional explanation, the concepts aren't that difficult at all!

Comment: Ok this definitely pointed me in the right direction! First and foremost, I realized that the two-step method of doing a merge then drop was probably what I was after, but I was stuck in the mental model of "there must be a one step method."

Now, specific to your code: (1) I was able to achieve the merge without adding the generic "var" columns; can you elaborate on the purpose of those?, and (2) in my specific use case, I didn't need a clean version of df1, so I could do everything in place there rather than creating additional data frames.

TLDR: This is what I wound up doing.

Comment: the purpose of var was to create a merged dataframe with every possible outcome of both dataframes, it's called a cross join in sql server and Cartesian join elsewhere. why don't you post your solution as an answer?